# Pass data to background agent, C# windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background-process

Did quite a bit of reading on how to get data from my main app to the background agent. Microsoft suggestion seems to be to use isolated storage with mutex.

It is suggested in a few places that you can create a static class in a third project (referenced by main and agent) and pass the data that way (but no samples). I could not get that to work. The background agent did not seem to have access to the static class created by the main app.

Has anyone got that to work? Or is isolated storage the best way?

Answer (score 5):

What you have read in a few places is completely impossible by design.

Background agents live in a separate process. If you'll define static variable in a shared library, you'll have 2 completely independent copies of that variable, one in the GUI process, another one in the background agent process.